# Scroll tableView with UIButton visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uistoryboard

I have a TableView that contains a prototype cell and a UIView with a button in it. It looks like this:

[image]

I have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the tableView to get to the button.

What I am trying to achieve is to keep the button visible at the bottom while the tableView is scrolling at the upper part of the screen.

How can I do that?

Comment: The easier solution is layout both the table view and the button on a view.(use view controller instead of table view controller）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't like the idea of ditching the UITableViewConvtroller so I ended up doing it via:

```
//self.floatingActionButtonYOrigin is initialised with the initial Y origin in viewDidLoad.

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let tableBounds = self.tableView.bounds
    var floatingButtonFrame = self.bottomRightButton.frame;
    floatingButtonFrame.origin.y = self.floatingActionButtonYOrigin + tableBounds.origin.y;
    self.bottomRightButton.frame = floatingButtonFrame;
}
```

It doesn't respect orientation changes though..